# Explain Example on Maximal Element with sets

Tags: elementary-set-theory, terminology

I am trying to understand [maximal element](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximal_element) and I cannot understand this example from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximal_element)

> *As an example, in the collection*
>
> $$S = \{\{d, o\}, \{d, o, g\}, \{g, o, a, d\}, \{o, a, f\}\}$$
>
> *ordered by containment, the element $\{d, o\}$ is minimal, the element $\{g, o, a, d\}$ is maximal, the element $\{d, o, g\}$ is neither, and the element $\{o, a, f\}$ is both minimal and maximal. By contrast, neither a maximum nor a minimum exists for $S$.*

where I cannot understand

**What does the order by containment really mean?**

> 1. why is $\{d,o\}$ minimal?
> 2. why is $\{g,o,a,d\}$ maximal?
> 3. why is $\{d,o,g\}$ nor maximal nor minimal?
> 4. why is $\{o,a,f\}$ both minimal and maximal?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Ordered by containment" means that if we are considering subsets of a set $S$ where $X\subset S$ and $Y\subset S$ then we say that $X\le Y$ (that is, "$X$ is less than $Y$" or "$X$ comes before $Y$") if $X\subset Y$ (that is, $X$ is contained in $Y$, equivalently $X$ is a subset of $Y$).

This is not a total order, so there may be no smallest (or minimum) element $X$ in the sense that $X\le Y$ for all $Y\subset S$. Instead we have a concept of a **minimal** element $X$ where $X\le Y$ for all those $Y$ for which $X\le Y$ or $Y\le X$. This is not the same thing as a mini**mum** element, since for some $Y\subset S$ we may have that neither $X\subset Y$ nor $Y\subset X$.

The test for minimality can be stated as follows:

1. We are given a set $P$ with a partial order $\le$ defined on it. We choose $x\in P$. Is $x$ minimal?
2. Look at $Q=\{y\in P|x\le y\vee y\le x\}\subset P$. This set $Q$ is the set of all elements which are **comparable** to $x$ using $\le$.
3. For each $z\in Q$ check that $x\le z$.
4. If you found some $z\in Q$ such that $z\le x$ in the last step then $x$ is not minimal. Maybe $z$ is minimal, maybe not. If you did not find any $z\in Q$ such that $z\le x$ in the last step, then $x$ is minimal.

Comment: Can you explain with the example of the Q why is $\{d,o,g\}$ not maximal? $\{d,o\}<\{d,o,g\}$ and $\{d,o\}<\{g,o,a,d\}$ so each of $\{d,o,g\}$ and $\{g,o,a,d\}$ is larger than one set so they both are maximal? Right? And $\{o,a,f\}\not\subset S_i$ for any $i$ so what is $\{o,a,f\}$?

Comment: I edited my answer to describe a test for minimality.  The test for maximality is analogous.  As far as "what is $\{o,a,f\}$", consider the set $Q$ in that case.  It would just be $Q=\{\{o,a,f\}\}$, so we would find that $\{o,a,f\}$ is both minimal and maximal.

Comment: What is a situation where $Q_2=\{y\in P\mid x\leq y \land y\leq x\}$ (and, not or)? I am also trying to think a situation like [this](http://i.stack.imgur.com/v6koK.png) where $a\leq b\leq a$, that would mean that $a$ and $b$ are comparable?

Comment: We say that $a$ and $b$ are comparable as long as either $a\le b$ or $b\le a$, so $a$ and $b$ are certainly comparable if both $a\le b$ and $b\le a$. Part of the definition of a partial order is that $a\le b\le a$ implies that $a=b$, so your set $Q_2$ would just contain $x$ itself.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

This is easy to show with Hasse diagram. I will first demonstrate a pedagocal example and then this example.

**Example**

I use [Hasse diagram](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hasse_diagram) to describe a poset $(S_2,\geq)$ with a set $$S_2=\{\{d\},\{d,o\},\{d,o,a\},\{d,a\},\{d,a,g\},\{g,o,a,d\}\}$$

[image]

where $\{g,o,a,d\}$ is the maximal while $\{d\}$ is the minimal by the containment, here I think they are also the maximum and the minimum, respectivily ordered by the containment (or set inclusion): $\{d\}\subseteq S_i$ while $\{g,o,a,d\}\not\subset S_i$ unless the same set. The $\{d,o\}$ and the $\{d,a\}$ are incomparable elements.

**Example in the question**

The latter example is very similar to your given example with

$$S = \{\{d, o\}, \{d, o, g\}, \{g, o, a, d\}, \{o, a, f\}\}$$

where I could not understand why $\{g,o,a,d\}$ is maximal and $\{o,a,f\}$ is nor maximal neither minimal: I think $\{o,a,f\}$ is incomparable to any set in $S$ so it is both maximal and minimal

[image]

where $\{o\}\not\subset S_i$. So $\{d,o,g\}\geq\{d,o\}$ and $\{g,o,a,d\}\geq\{d,o\}$ but $\{d,o,g\}\not\geq \{o,a,f\}$. So I would say that $\{g,o,a,d\}$ and $\{o,a,f\}$ are maximal elements. The minimal elements are $\{o,a,f\}$ and $\{d,o\}$

[image]

and as a matter of fact, this conclusion is the same as in the Wikipedia, now explained with Hasse diagram, hurray!

---

**Further reading**

- Wikipedia on [Comparability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparability)
- Wikipedia on [Comparability Graphs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparability_graph) (Hasse diagrams and comparability graphs [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bFqmZ.png))
- For learning Tikz, a small [demo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jnDKG.png) on generating the lattices and [learning](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/30504856#30504856).